# How to change a value in memory space of another process

Tags: c++, c, windows, linux, memory-management

If you could help me with this dilemma I have. Now, I know C \ C++, I know asm, I know about dll injection, I know about virtual memory addressing, but I just can't figure out how
software like CheatEngine, and others, manage to change a variable's value in another process.

For those who don't know, 3rd party cheat engine tools can scan for values in the memory space of a program and identify the location of a variable with a given value and change it.

My question is, how do they do it?

Given an address, if I were to write C code, how could I change the value at that address belonging to another process without getting an invalid addressing error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm fairly certain those programs are pretending to be debuggers.  On Windows, I would start with [DebugActiveProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679295(VS.85).aspx) and go from there.

Oh, and the very useful looking [ReadProcessMemory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553(VS.85).aspx) function (and WriteProcessMemory()).

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for, works great. (For others reading this solution be sure to use DebugActiveProcessStop when done)

Comment: Be sure to call DebugSetProcessKillOnExit() if you don't want the process you're debugging to die after you're done debugging it.

Answer (score 5):

On unix: ptrace()

Comment: Can ptrace also modify the memory of the other process?

Comment: As opposed to which process?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with Standard C or C++ - you have to use operating system specific features. So you need to tell us which OS you are interested in.

Comment: Sorry i did not specify, i am interested in Windows, but Linux would be great to, i am curious to try it there also

Answer (score 2):

You may also be interested in [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/):

> Software packaged for detouring Win32 and application APIs.

Comment: Thanks read about detouring http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/how-i-built-a-working-online-poker-bot-7. Fun experiment ASCII \ graffiti bomb. Too bad it's not freely \ easily available for 64 bit