# Is it possible using memory writing to invoke actions on another applicaiton

Tags: c#, .net

I really have a hard time figuring out the title for this, but basically
There is independent map application(similar to gmaps), each time I open it reads 
the coordinates from text file and shows the labels on map.
You can add the labels to the map yourself and it saves them to the coordinate file after
you close the application.

Question: is there a way I can make it so that my application puts the labels on the map
using some kind of memory writing? I can use the coordinate file for that application and write the coordinates there, but I want the labels show up without re-opening the application.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand yet. Please elaborate

Comment: Sounds like you want some form of IPC however both source and target would need to support it.

Comment: If all you want to do is show labels without re-opening, can you not just refresh you controls to reload their children controls? How are you storing the coords?

Comment: @Shane.C the map app is not mine nor i have a source code for it, I need to figure it out how to add the coordinates to that application from my application programmatically without clicking to add the label.

Comment: @EverWondeR, most likeli it will not be worth it. It is probably much more easier to reverse-enginer the map program to allow rudimentary IPC for reloading the text file that to alter its memory on the fly. 
What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate x64

Comment: @EverWondeR, I don't know much about windows, but I think you at least you need superuser privileges to access other process memory.

There is another question about writing to memory in windows (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623029/how-can-i-write-on-another-process-memory).

Comment: @Panu ok i'll look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this is not possible because writing to the memory area reserved of other application is prohibited by operating system and by processor architechture. If you have unprivileged access to memory this would be possible, but unpractical in reality.

You need some inter-process communication, but this requires support from both applications.

Comment: "..but this requires support from both applications." thats the problem.. and I'm trying to find other ways, hacky or not..