# How do I find a memory address programmatically...?

Tags: c#, debugging, memory

I have a problem with a memory address.
I know that the memory addresses always changes if the software is closed and re-opened.

How do I accomplish that my program always find the right memory address?
I wanna read an exact value this is my plan.

Please help with an example (source code).

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Maybe take a look at lower level languages and pointers (C++ or C). Also, progrmas have their own address spaces.

Comment: Not sure what you want, but have a look at this, might lead you somewhere http://stackoverflow.com/q/4623029/340760

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read another process memory as [described here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670373/Csharp-Read-Write-another-Process-Memory).

But first you should find some pointer to address of your value with never changing address. You can use something like [Cheat Engine](http://www.cheatengine.org/) (pointer scan) or [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/) (read/write breakpoints and analyzing disassembled code) to do this.

Then you can read actual address of value that you needed from this pointer.