# I´m using ctypes to read 64 bit memory. Is there a way to calculate the memory address of a variable with a pointer?

Tags: python, pointers, 64-bit, ctypes, memory-address

This is the code I am using, but how can i convert the memory address with a pointer I have created? I am using this way of reading memory, so i can get 64 bit values, but it is kind of annoying to look up the new memory addresses each time I start the .exe.

```
import ctypes as c
from ctypes import wintypes as w
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

pid = 14840

k32 = c.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)

OpenProcess = k32.OpenProcess
OpenProcess.argtypes = w.DWORD,w.BOOL,w.DWORD
OpenProcess.restype = w.HANDLE


ReadProcessMemory = k32.ReadProcessMemory
ReadProcessMemory.argtypes = w.HANDLE,w.LPCVOID,w.LPVOID,c.c_size_t,c.POINTER(c.c_size_t)
ReadProcessMemory.restype = w.BOOL

CloseHandle = k32.CloseHandle
CloseHandle.argtypes = [w.HANDLE]
CloseHandle.restype = w.BOOL


processHandle = OpenProcess(0x10, False, pid)
# POINTER: 0x00007FF6D4CA0000 + 0x02172560

while 1:
    addr = 0x00007FF6D4CA0000  
    data = c.c_ulonglong()
    bytesRead = c.c_ulonglong()
    result = ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, c.c_void_p(addr), c.byref(data), c.sizeof(data), 
    c.byref(bytesRead))
    e = c.get_last_error()

    print('result: {}, err code: {}, bytesRead: {}'.format(result,e,bytesRead.value))
    print('data: {:016X}h'.format(data.value))
    
CloseHandle(processHandle)
```

Comment: You need a way to calculate or scan for the address. Since you are on Windows, check out [pymem](https://github.com/srounet/Pymem). Also see this answer for more links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28928500/how-do-i-find-a-memory-address-programmatically

Comment: A pointer **is** the address of a variable. I don't understand what the problem is. What is the above code doing and what it should do?