# Write / read process memory

Tags: .net, powershell, winapi

How to write / read the memory of any process?

As I understand, I have to use **WriteProcessMemory** / **ReadProcessMemory** winapi functions.

Here is whith what i start:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition '
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class winapi{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]public static extern Boolean WriteProcessMemory(
        IntPtr hProcess,
        IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
        IntPtr lpBuffer,
        UInt32 nSize,
        ref UInt32 lpNumberOfBytesWritten
    );
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]public static extern Boolean ReadProcessMemory( 
        IntPtr hProcess, 
        IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
        IntPtr lpBuffer,
        UInt32 dwSize, 
        ref UInt32 lpNumberOfBytesRead
    );
}
'

[IntPtr]$mem = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::AllocHGlobal(4)

$dataToWrite = "ABC"

[IntPtr]$hProcess = $pid
[IntPtr]$lpBaseAddress = $mem
[IntPtr]$lpBuffer
[UInt32]$nSize
[UInt32]$BytesWritten

$CallResult = [winapi]::WriteProcessMemory(
    $hProcess,
    $lpBaseAddress,
    $lpBuffer,
    $nSize,
    [ref]$BytesWritten
)
$CallResult

[IntPtr]$hProcess = $pid
[IntPtr]$lpBaseAddress  = $mem
[UInt32]$ReadSize = 4
[IntPtr]$lpBuffer = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::AllocHGlobal($ReadSize)
[UInt32]$BytesRead = 0 

$CallResult = [winapi]::ReadProcessMemory(
    $hProcess,
    $lpBaseAddress,
    $lpBuffer,
    $ReadSize,
    [ref]$BytesRead
)
$CallResult

# As I understand, here I should get "ABC"

[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::FreeHGlobal($mem)
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::FreeHGlobal($lpBuffer)
```

I need to read some processes memory / write processes memory.

How to do it correctly?

Comment: Add `$destArray = [byte[]]::new($BytesRead);[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::Copy($lpBuffer, $destArray, 0, $BytesRead)` before the `FreeHGlobal()` calls at the buttom - will copy the read memory stored in the unmanaged `$lpBuffer` to `$destArray` - but it won't correspond to `$dataToWrite`, because you didn't actually write anything in the first place :)

Comment: *"How to do it correctly?"* Er, the first step is figuring out, which address to read from/write to. That's the hard part. The question you asked about is the trivial part, that's been asked and answered literally hundreds of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take them one at a time.

### WriteProcessMemory

In order to write *something* to *somewhere* in *some process*, you need to pass the correct arguments:

#### `lpBuffer`

The `lpBuffer` argument must point to the data that needs to be written.

There's a couple of ways to produce a safe pointer to an existing object, I prefer this approach:

```bsh
$dataToWrite = "ABC"

# Encode data in byte array 
$dataArray   = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($dataToWrite)

# Pin the object in memory (ensures the garbage collector doesn't move the source data around)
$pinnedArray = [Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle]::Alloc($dataArray, [Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandleType]::Pinned)

# Now we can obtain a safe pointer to the array
[IntPtr]$lpBuffer = $pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject()
```

But the far easier approach would be to just declare `lpBuffer` a `byte[]` in the first place and have the runtime take care of all that (sans the string encoding):

```cs
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]public static extern Boolean WriteProcessMemory(
    IntPtr hProcess,
    IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
    byte[] lpBuffer,
    UInt32 nSize,
    ref UInt32 lpNumberOfBytesWritten
);
```

#### `hProcess`

For the `hProcess` argument, you need a process *handle* - passing the `PID` of the owning  process directly won't work.

For the current process (ie. the executing PowerShell host application), you can use `Get-Process`:

```bsh
# Obtain handle to current process
$hProcess = (Get-Process -Id $PID).Handle
```

But for a *different* process, you'll need to call [`Kernel32!OpenProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess) - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4623200/712649) has an excellent example of how to import and declare the access flag parameter type:

```cs
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(
    ProcessAccessFlags dwDesiredAccess, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    bool bInheritHandle,
    int dwProcessId);
```

```cs
[Flags]
public enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
{
    All = 0x001F0FFF,
    Terminate = 0x00000001,
    CreateThread = 0x00000002,
    VMOperation = 0x00000008,
    VMRead = 0x00000010,
    VMWrite = 0x00000020,
    DupHandle = 0x00000040,
    SetInformation = 0x00000200,
    QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
    Synchronize = 0x00100000
}
```

#### `lpBaseAddress`

`[Marshal]::AllocHGlobal($size)` will only help you when writing to the current process.

For allocation in a *different process*, you'll need to pass a writeable process handle obtained via `OpenProcess()` to [`Kernel32!VirtualAllocEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualallocex):

```cs
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true) ]
public extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(
    IntPtr hProcess,
    IntPtr lpAddress,
    UInt32 dwSize,
    AllocationType flAllocationType,
    MemoryProtection flProtect);
```

```cs
[Flags]
public enum AllocationType
{
     Commit = 0x1000,
     Reserve = 0x2000,
     Decommit = 0x4000,
     Release = 0x8000,
     Reset = 0x80000,
     Physical = 0x400000,
     TopDown = 0x100000,
     WriteWatch = 0x200000,
     LargePages = 0x20000000
}

[Flags]
public enum MemoryProtection
{
     Execute = 0x10,
     ExecuteRead = 0x20,
     ExecuteReadWrite = 0x40,
     ExecuteWriteCopy = 0x80,
     NoAccess = 0x01,
     ReadOnly = 0x02,
     ReadWrite = 0x04,
     WriteCopy = 0x08,
     GuardModifierflag = 0x100,
     NoCacheModifierflag = 0x200,
     WriteCombineModifierflag = 0x400
}
```

`VirtualAllocEx` will write the base address of the allocation to the `lpAddress` pointer on success.

---

### ReadProcessMemory

Finally, to *read* the resulting data, you'll need to copy the data referenced by the `lpBuffer` argument to an array:

```bsh
$CallResult = [winapi]::ReadProcessMemory(
    $hProcess,
    $lpBaseAddress,
    $lpBuffer,
    $ReadSize,
    [ref]$BytesRead
)

if($CallResult){
  $destArray = [byte[]]::new($BytesRead)
  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::Copy($lpBuffer, $destArray, 0, $BytesRead)

  $stringRead = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($destArray)
  Write-Host "Read data from process memory: $stringRead"
}
```